# ¿Constructor con variable miembro?

Tags: c++, string, constructor, diseño-de-clases

Tengo una duda con respecto al siguiente main

```
#include "Pokemon.h"

int main()
{
Pokemon piplup("Piplup", Pokemon::Agua);
piplup.mostrar();
cout << endl << endl;
}
```

He de decir que el main es una referencia que el profesor nos paso para usar las clases. Mi pregunta es referente a la primera línea, el parametro del constructor `Pokemon::Agua` si no me equivoco hace referencia a una variable miembro, es decir, agua. 
Sin embargo, estoy perdido cuando realizo la clase pokemon, ya que en las instrucciones del ejercicio dice que cada **pokemon tiene un nombre y solo pueden ser de cuatro tipos, agua, tierra, aire y fuego**. Ademas de los metodos que yo hice, a continuancion el header, debe haber uno para **obtener un string con el nombre del tipo dado el codigo del tipo y si es necesario incluir constantes en la clase pokemon**. 
Tengo la clase asi, pero no entiendo como implementar el constructor para que desde el main se llame como el main de referencia

```
#ifndef POKEMON_H
#define POKEMON_H
#include <string>
using std::string;

class Pokemon
{
        string nombre;
        string tipo;
    public:
        string getTipo ();
    //Constructores 
        Pokemon();
        Pokemon (string nombre, string tipo);

        ~Pokemon();

    //Metodos de acceso
        string getNombre ();
        string getTipo (string tipo);
        void setNombre (string nombre);
        void setTipo (string tipo);


    //Metodo utilitario
        void mostrar ();    

};

#endif
```

Si me pueden ayudar les agradeceria mucho !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> si no me equivoco hace referencia a una variable miembro

Incompleto. Hace referencia a una variable miembro ... `static`. O a una `enum`, considerando a estas como una variante especial de variables `static`.

Las *cosas*-miembro-estáticas son aquellas que se acceden sin necesitar una instancia de la clase; podríamos decir que *pertenecen* a la clase en si.

Para acceder a ellas *desde fuera* de la clase, es necesario identificarlas tal y como expones, indicando la clase a la que pertenecen.

Usando variables-miembro-estáticas y C++11, tu clase quedaría así:

```
class Pokemon {
  string nombre;
  string tipo;

public:
  static int Agua = 1;
  static int Tierra = 1;
  static int Aire = 3;
  static int Fuego = 4;

  Pokemon();
  Pokemon( string nombre, int tipo );
  ...
```

Indico lo de C++11 porque en versiones anteriores no se puede inicializar las variables estáticas **en la propia declaración** de clase; se debe de hacer en un archivo diferente.

Otra posible opción, que **si** es válida para C++ anterior al 11, es usar una `enum`:

```
class Pokemon {
  string nombre;
  int tipo;

public:
  enum {
    Agua = 1,
    Tierra,
    Aire,
    Fuego,
  };
  ...
```

Con lo cual ahora tienes 2 opciones para tu constructor: seguir usando un `int`, lo que lo hace propenso a errores ... o aprovechar que es una `enum`, y el compilador tomará nota de ello y no permitirá usar valores incorrectos.

Para hacer esto, son necesarios pequeños cambios: hay que declarar `TipoDePoquemon` **antes** de usarlo, y cambiar el tipo de la variable-miembro:

```
class Pokemon {
public:
  enum TipoDePoquemon {
    Agua = 1,
    Tierra,
    Aire,
    Fuego,
  };

private:
  string nombre;
  TipoDePoquemon tipo;

public:
  enum TipoDePoquemon {
    Agua = 1,
    Tierra,
    Aire,
    Fuego,
  };

  Pokemon( );
  Pokemon( string nombre, TipoDePoquemon tipo );
  ...
```

En este último caso, si intentas llamar al constructor con un valor incorrecto ...

```
Pokemon pikachu( "pikachu", 5 );
```

> error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'Pokemon::TipoDePoquemon'
>   note: initializing argument 2 of 'Pokemon::Pokemon(std::string, Pokemon::TipoDePoquemon)'

Es necesario llamarlo con uno de los valores correctos de `TipoDePoquemon`:

```
Pokemon pikachu( "pikachu", Pokemon::Aire );
```

Comment: ¡ Huy ! He puesto a `pikachu` como de tipo `Aire` ... espero que ningún *purista* se de cuenta :-)

Comment: Jaja justamente mi profesor también puso a pikachu como tipo aire, agradezco mucho tu respuesta, @Trauma !

Comment: tengo una duda, puedo cambiar el valor de una variable static ?

Comment: Si, claro. Es una variable como otra cualquiera. Y sigue los *controles de acceso* normales; si es `public`, pues se puede cambiar desde fuera de la clase. A menos que la declares `const`.

Comment: me referia entre objetos, es decir, que una variable static tenga un valor diferente para un objeto 1 y para un objeto 2, asi sucesivamente, practicamente asignar diferentes valores y que no se borren. Lo he intentado pero se sobreescriben ;( @Trauma